# Create a new database problem

Tags: sql-server, database, sa

I'm logging in to create a new database from CMD through sqlcmd with SA account. Its response is a message: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

I'm using Windows server 2003 and SQL 2008. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the exact command you're using to create the database?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you're actually using the sa account, or else perhaps you haven't set up your service account properly using SQL config mgr. If you used Computer Manager | Services, then the service might not have permission to create the database files.

Answer (score 0):

...Run As Administrator should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the user you're using to run the SQL Server service will not have access to certain folders, which is likely why you're getting this error.

Consider one of these alternatives:

- change the credentials used for the service (ick!)
- use `runas /u:...` or `Run as...`
- add permission for the service to access those folders
- move the database to a location that the service can access

Answer (score 0):

I would check whether the user you are using indeed has CREATE DATABASE permission though. You can check what **server roles** it belongs to, because it seems it is not a sysadmin role.

You can use this query for example.

```
select suser_name(role_principal_id) [login ...], 
suser_name(member_principal_id) [... belongs to] 
from sys.server_role_members
```

Regards

Piotr